# Excel Find and compare values over multiple columns if condition met

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, find

I have a table with rows representing clients and, each month, i add a column on each row representing the type of orders they make (A, B or C).

I need to identify every client who made an order of type A (in any month) and then, in one of the following months, made a type C order.

However, IF after going from "A" to a "C" type order (one or more months doing a "C"), the client returns to an "A", i don't need to identify him.

"B" orders are indifferent after finding an "A" order

Example given:

```
Client  M1  M2  M3  M4  Identify
  01    A   B   C   C     Yes
  02    A   B   C   A      No
  03    A   C   B   A      No
  04    B   B   A   C     Yes
  05    B   A   C   B     Yes
  06    C   A   B   B      No
  07    A   A   A   C     Yes
  08    A   A   A   A      No
  09    A   C   A   C     Yes
  10    A   C   C   A      No
```

Etc.

I don't know if i can do it with a simple formula or using VBA.

**EDITED:** Since every month i add a new column, formula or VBA should consider all possibilities (like "ACCA", "ACCCCA", and so on). Also added clients 07, 08, 09 and 10 as an example.

Thank you in advance.

JT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without VBA an *easy* way would be: (in F2 and then copy down)

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("AC",SUBSTITUTE(B2&C2&D2&E2,"B",""))),"No",IF(ISERROR(FIND("ACA",SUBSTITUTE(B2&C2&D2&E2,"B",""))),"Yes","No"))
```

As an "OnlyDoesWhatIAskedFor"-UDF put this in module:

```
Public Function getOrder(rng As Range) As String
  Dim runner As Variant, i As Long, comb As Variant
  comb = Array("A", "C", "A")
  getOrder = "No"
  For Each runner In rng.Value
    If runner = comb(i) Then
      If i = 2 Then getOrder = "No": Exit Function
      If i = 1 Then getOrder = "Yes"
      i = i + 1
    ElseIf runner = comb(0) Then
      i = 1
    ElseIf runner <> "B" Then
      i = 0
    End If
  Next
End Function
```

then in the cell to output (asuming F2 and simply copy down)

```
=getOrder(B2:E2)
```

it just checks for the A-C order in the range while B will be ignored and A-C-A also outputs "No"...

**EDIT**

If only the last AC/ACA count then you would need something like this: (in Module)

```
Public Function getResult(rng As Range) As String
  Dim a As Variant, b As String
  'Col W - changes the cells to one long string / "B" will be left out
  For Each a In rng.Value
    If a <> "B" Then b = b & a
  Next
  'Col X - skips xxACAxx to Axx till no ACA is left
  While InStr(b, "ACA")
    b = Mid(b, InStr(b, "ACA") + 2)
  Wend
  '<~~~ add from here for ACCA = "No" (ACCAC will still be "YES")
  While InStr(b, "ACCA")
    b = Mid(b, InStr(b, "ACCA") + 2)
  Wend
  '<~~~ add till here for ACCA = "No" (ACCAC will still be "YES")
  'Col Y - Checks if an AC is found in the leftover
  'Col Z - if the check is >0 then it will be YES else No
  If InStr(b, "AC") Then getResult = "Yes" Else getResult = "No"
End Function
```

You can see each step it does in the following picture: 
[image]

Comment: @J.T. just a question... if there is an ACAC order is it "yes" or "no"?

Comment: Thank you! I tried the formula without VBA and It works like a charm. And i actually didn't consider that case, i guess it should be a "yes". I could make another FIND("ACAC" if "ACA" condition was met. However, the formula would grow as months are added (every month i add a new column). Same would happen with Array on VBA.

Comment: Right now both versions are only true if no ACA but at least one AC was found... so the question simply is: does only the last AC/ACA count?

Comment: You're right, didn't know find formula worked like that. Thanks!  What if there's an "ACCA" or "ACCCA" though (considering more months). Sorry for not specifying that case before, will add it on post.

Comment: @J.T. only AC/ACA will be checked... nothing else... pls see my edit for a way just checking for last AC/ACA...

Comment: I actually did need to check the last AC / ACA. My sincere apologize for not answering properly your question earlier. Problem solved. By the way, just as some plus, would the function work for the example of Client "10" i recently added? "ACCA" = "No"

Comment: @J.T. ACCA would be act as a "Yes"... if you need it to be "No" insert the code between the two `'<~~~` in my edited answer :)

Comment: Awesome Dirk! Thank you a lot. This will help me a lot at work! Going to get the data and test it.